# Tcp connection establishes connection to server but then goes to time wait and a new connection is established with port incrementation

Tags: tcp, port

Here is the sequence I am seeing on tcpview:

Application establishes connection to server on port 443 (SSL)
Some data is returned from the server to the application
After about a second this tcp connection goes to TIME_WAIT
Application then establishes a new tcp connection to server with the port number incremented
Some data is returned from the server to the application
After about a second this tcp connection goes to TIME_WAIT
...This repeats about every second

Any ideas why this is occurring ??!

Comment: At a rough guess, the connection is being closed by the server.

Comment: Yes that looks to be the case but trying to determine the reason why.  Firewall, Internet svcs config, server getting hit with lots of api calls therefore thinks it's a dos attack...Have put the ? on the application community forum  but no joy yet...thanks for the response!

Comment: Which application does this?

Comment: It's a SOAP SAAS based marketing automation website...